# How to get Excel sheet size

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I need to know how many rows of my sheet will be printed (after the PDF conversion) on each page.

I hoped to calculate each row's size and sum it with top and bottom margin to figure it out.

Example: top and margin - 1 unit, 10 rows - 10 units. A4 fits 10 units => First page will contain 8 rows (8 units + 1 top margin + 1 bot margin).

In reality, I haven't found the precise correlation between size and how many rows will be on page. I've tried it on real .xlsx: converted all units to inches, but row may appear even if it exceeds A4 page size.

Is there a decent way to find amount of rows on page?

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution but perhaps not 100% fool proof. Excel will show its own automatic page breaks (a dashed line) when clicking view -> page break view. I found somewhere that Apache POI cannot detect these page breaks when they are page format dependent, in other words, it doesn't know the size of the "page" you would want. I tried to get it to detect it but I didn't not succeed.

However, here is my approach and solution:

1. I start off with mixing with the excel file (in excel) to get where the automatic page break gets inserted, then I calculate in java the summed height of these rows with this code:

```
try {
                    
  FileInputStream file=new FileInputStream(pathToFile);
  XSSFWorkbook wb=new XSSFWorkbook(file);
  XSSFSheet sheet0=wb.getSheetAt(0);
            
  float sizeOfPage=0;
  for(int i =0 ; i<end; i++) { //here end should be equal to the last row before 
                               //the automatic page break gets inserted
                
     sizeOfPage=sizeOfPage + sheet0.getRow(i).getHeightInPoints();
  
  } 

  System.out.println(sizeOfPage); //this is the value you need to get 
                                            //calculated
            
  wb.close();
  file.close();
        
}
        
catch (IOException e) {
            
}
```

2. I then used the value sizeOfPage in the following code to get my code to detect when I need to put in an extra page break. NOTE: Here my goal is to find out if the segment I want to keep intact fits without having a page break inserted into it. My segment was at the end of the document.

```
  float length=0; //the length of the whole document
  int i =0;                                 
                                                                 
  while(i<sheet0MakeQuotationMod.getLastRowNum()-1) { //note that the indexing is 
                                                      //different in the excel and 
                                                       //the code, I had trouble 
                                                      //getting this working....
                                        
      length=length + sheet0MakeQuotationMod.getRow(i).getHeightInPoints();
      i++;
  }
                                
  float lengthFull=length
  int counter=0;
  while(length>=sizeOfPage) { //to see how many pages
       
       length/=sizeOfPage;
       counter++;
                                        
  }
                                    
  double spaceLeft=lengthFull-(sizeOfPage*counter); //to see how much space is left 
                                                    //on the last page
                                                                        
  if(spaceLeft<spaceINeed) { //if this holds, it means that the part I want to be on 
                              //the same page would get separated. I calculated this  
                            //with the same code as above.
                      
      //this row break is being applied where I want the segment to be separated
      //so that the segment gets shifted to the next page.
      sheet0MakeQuotationMod.setRowBreak(indexWhereIWantItToBeSeparated);
  }
```

Hope this helps! Please ask if something is unclear and I will try to clarify. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's actually how I did it in my first time.
Unfortunately, there's a lack of precision, cause I don't know how many rows   page can fit (row's size can vary).
So, my current realisation is:
Take approximate size of page in points ->  split the rows by pages (according to apprx size) ->  create sheet for each page -> set print settings .fitToPage()  -> now all rows fits for sure and the printed doc has a consistent view

Answer (score 0):

If you use `XSSFSheet`, then you can use `sheet.getLastRow()`, if you use some other, then use `sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows()`. All implementations of Sheet interface have this.

Comment: Yep, but its just a physical number of the row. 
And I need the amount of rows one printed page (not sheet) can fit